# How do I Compile Just One C File in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

I don't have experience using Visual Studio. The university is conducting a C coding competition and forcing students to use Visual Studio. To practice I created 2 files: "to print helloworld", "finding smallest in the array". Visual studio builds ALL files and I want to create multiple files to save time and keep it ready to code but if I am working on one question and build it, all files get built. How to build one file? Please help.

Comment: This comment won't help but I am curious: why on earth is it required to use Visual Studio in a competition? One can use any IDE (s)he wants! Is there any sponsorship there?

Comment: You might want to organise one project in one folder, rather than jumble them up all in the same folder.

Comment: @WeatherVane will try

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to organize your code into `Projects` and `Solutions`. You use one `Project` per program you write and then group them in a `Solution`.

Se the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019